# Cannot share a base 64 image through fb messenger using react-native-share

Tags: react-native

I want to share a image using react-native-share. I can share the image through every social media except Facebook messenger. Why it is not possible to share a image through messenger using react-native share.Is there a way to do this.

my code as follows so far

```
   if (as === "image") {
  Shares.open({
    title: "React Native",
    message: "This is a test message just ignore it",
    url:
      "data:image/png;base64,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",
    subject: "Share Link"
  });
} else {
  Shares.open({
    title: "React Native",
    message: "Hola mundo",
    url: "www.google.lk",
    subject: "Share Link"
  });
}
```

};

how cam i do this.

Comment: If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept an answer for further references.

Comment: single or multiple images sharing using react-native-share, answer by me with more detailed info here, checkout  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67016851/want-to-share-multiple-images-with-separate-caption-to-each-image-whatsapp-reac/67167916#67167916

Answer (score 0):

You can share through Facebook Messenger using [React Native share API](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/share.html)

As you can see [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share/issues/150), this is a feature request in the `react-native-share`