# Want to share multiple images with separate caption to each image Whatsapp, react native share

Tags: react-native

I am using React Native Share library, a good one,
I just need little help,

It is sharing multiple images with same caption,

i just want to share multiple images with separate message (caption) to each image,

suppose, if there is 5 images, then caption to 5 images is different not same.

In current situation, it share 5 images with same message (caption)

Here is my code

var imgs=["base64IMAGE1...///","base64IMAGE2..///","base64IMAGE3..///"];
let shareImage = {
title:"title",
message:"this is message need to send separate to each image",
urls:abcc,
subject: "Image"
};
Share.open(shareImage).catch(err => console.log(err));

I have attached current situation screenshots..

[image 1 on whatsapp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diPd6.jpg)
[image 2 on whatsapp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N04qn.jpg)

all sent with same caption, i just to send multiple images with separate messages

ThankYou.

Comment: can you share little bit of code snippet what you've tried so far.

Comment: Hi, i am trying to share multiple images with separate caption to each image,
here is my code, its sending same caption to each image 
 
 var imgs=[img1,img2,img3];

  let shareImage = {
              title:`message 1`,//string
              message:`message 1`,//string
              urls:imgs,
              subject: "Image" 
        };
      Share.open(shareImage).catch(err => console.log(err));

Comment: can you give me code snippet, do not paste code in comment section.. example: expo snack - https://snack.expo.io/ for react native or codeSandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-snow-b1b4g for react js

Comment: ok i am doing it now

Comment: i have made it on expo, i have put my code in one function, 
i am using react-native-share

https://snack.expo.io/@msh1931/authentic-yogurt

Comment: sure. let me check

Comment: given answer, check and let me know

Answer (score 1):

I've created working example to share multiple or single images using [react-native-share](https://react-native-share.github.io/react-native-share/docs/share-open)

[CheckOut ExpoSnack Here](https://snack.expo.io/@klakshman318/sharemultiorsingleimagesrn)

[image: ReactNativeShareImage]

added comments before every method what it'll do and what needs to be replaced.

```
// multiple images share example
const shareMultipleImages = async () => {
    const shareOptions = {
        title: 'Share multiple files example',
        // here replace base64 data with your local filepath
        // base64 with mimeType or path to local file
        urls: [base64ImagesData.image1, base64ImagesData.image2],
        failOnCancel: false,
    };

    // If you want, you can use a try catch, to parse
    // the share response. If the user cancels, etc.
    try {
        const ShareResponse = await Share.open(shareOptions);
        setResult(JSON.stringify(ShareResponse, null, 2));
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error =>', error);
        setResult('error: '.concat(getErrorString(error)));
    }
};
```

you can add local file path in shareMultipleImage method like this

> urls: Array of base64 string you want to share. base64 with mimeType or path to local file (Array[string])

[React Native Share Docs](https://react-native-share.github.io/react-native-share/docs/share-open)

```
const shareOptions = {
    title: 'Share multiple files example',
    urls: ["file..///","file..///","file..///"],
    failOnCancel: false,
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is also working fine on my side, but problem is when i share 3 files to whatsapp, then it will share 3 files with same message, same title on all images. But i need to send different title to each image on whatsapp

Comment: i don't see sharing multiple images with separate captions to each image using react-native-share as per docs yet. i see one open issue for this in official github repo, check it -https://github.com/react-native-share/react-native-share/issues/995

Comment: yeah, this issue also opened by me, 
I am just waiting for any moderator 

Thank You

Comment: yeah i know it was you who opened issue in git (recognized by title) :)  anyway tag me @klakshman318, if you get any replies in github.

Comment: OK Dude, i will tag you as i get any reply, still waiting for any moderator.

Thanks

Comment: It is working fine for me, but the problem is I want only one message on multiple images? how i can do it ?