# React native send an automatic message without opening whatsapp

Tags: react-native, mobile, whatsapp

I'm trying to send a text message to a WhatsApp contact from a react-native apps , i found that i can do it through Linking

```
Linking.openURL('whatsapp://send?text=hello');
```

the above code opens whatsapp. I would like to send message without opening whatsapp

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using `Share.shareSingle` from `react-native-share` package

```
const shareOptions = {
    title: 'Share via',
    message: 'some message',
    url: 'some share url',
    social: Share.Social.WHATSAPP,
    whatsAppNumber: "9199999999",  // country code + phone number
    filename: 'test' , // only for base64 file in Android
};

Share.shareSingle(shareOptions)
    .then((res) => { console.log(res) })
    .catch((err) => { err && console.log(err); });
```

> The shareSingle() method allows a user to share a premade message via
> a single prechosen social medium. In other words, code specifies both
> the message that will be sent and the social medium through which the
> message will be sent. The user chooses only to whom the message is
> sent. This shared message may contain text, one or more files, or
> both.

Checkout - https://react-native-share.github.io/react-native-share/docs/share-single

also i've given working example to share multiple or single images using `react-native-share` as answer to a question about how to do it. might be useful.

[Checkout Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67016851/want-to-share-multiple-images-with-separate-caption-to-each-image-whatsapp-reac#67167916)